# How to get the xpath for a link?

Tags: firefox, selenium, xpath, wicket, chromium

I'm writing selenium test for a wicket application and having trouble to get some xpaths.

For example:

I'm trying to get the xpath for a link. Here is the the link created by the wicket dynamically:

```html
<span>
 <a id="id2b3" href="#" onclick="var wcall=wicketAjaxGet('./participante_geral?7-1.IBehaviorListener.0-containerDiv-frameSetDiv-gridDiv-linhas-body-rows-1-cells-2-cell-linkPanel',function() { }.bind(this),function() { }.bind(this), function() {return Wicket.$('id2b3') != null;}.bind(this));return !wcall;">
  <span>Some String</span>
 </a>
</span>
```

I'm trying to get the xpath for the link like this:

```
//a/span[(text() = 'Some String')]/..
```

But when I run my selenium test the WebDriver for firefox, I can't locate the element/link.

When I run

```
$x("//a/span[(text() = 'Some String')]/..")
```

in chromium console I can locate the element with success.

But when I run the same  command in firefox I get an array containing the link.

What is wrong with my xpath?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Try to follow the following syntax when creating a xpath

//tagname[@attribute='value']

Answer (score 0):

Try to use `contains` function-

```
//a[@id='id2b3']/span[contains(text(), 'Some String')]
```

Answer (score 0):

Wicket supports rendering an extra attribute to each component for this use case, see IDebugSettings#setOutputComponentPath(boolean) [1]. This will render `wicketpath` attribute. You can use it like: `//a/[@wicketpath='grand:parent:child:id']`.
This is for Wicket 1.5.x/6.x.

For Wicket 7.x+ there is `DebugSettings#setComponentPathAttributeName(String)`. If it is non-null then Wicket will use this String as a name for the attribute, e.g. `data-wicket-path`.

1. https://github.com/apache/wicket/blob/wicket-1.5.x/wicket-core/src/main/java/org/apache/wicket/settings/IDebugSettings.java#L39